# 10 red cars, 10 blue cars, 10 green cars are distributed randomly in a line. What is the expected number of times a red car precedes a blue car?

Tags: probability, expectation

We can apply linearity of expectation to this to make it easier. This means we reduce the problem to finding the expectation that the red car i precedes the blue car j. This is just the probability of this event. I'm having trouble computing this probability. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Note that expectations are additive, that means $E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)$ and for every real number $a$ we have $E(aX)=aE(X)$. Try it from here.

Comment: As is too often the case, I do not understand the question. It says **the** red car. Which red car? Or is it **a** red car? And what does *precedes* mean? Immediately precedes?

Comment: yes; sorry I just made the clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We find the expected number of times that a red car *immediately precedes* a blue car. Imagine that the red cars are labelled $1$ to $10$.

Let $X_i=1$ if red car $i$ immediately precedes a blue car, and let $X_i=0$ otherwise. We want to find the expectation of $X_1+\cdots+X_{10}$. By the linearity of expectation and symmetry this is $10E(X_1)$.

We have $E(X_1)=\Pr(X_1=1)$. For $X_1$ to be $1$, red car $1$ must be in positions $1$ to $29$ (probability $\frac{29}{30}$). Given that it is in one of these positions, the probability there is a blue immediately behind it is $\frac{10}{29}$. Thus $\Pr(X_1=1)=\frac{10}{30}$.

Answer (score 0):

Using my words :

"A red car precedes a blue car" means that for any *particular* blue car: `...rb...` rather than `...gb...`, `...bb...`, or `b...`.   The later is when it is at the start of line, rather than any of the remaining $29$ positions.   Likewise of the remaining $29$ cars, there are $10$ red cars.

Thus for a particular blue car the probability that *some* car precedes it is $29/30$, and given that, then the conditional probability that the preceding car is red is $10/29$.   We multiply these to obtain that the expected number of times that *some red* car precedes *a particular* blue car is $1/3$.

There are totes ten blue cars, thus by Linearity of Expectation, the expected number of times *a* red car precedes *a* blue car is $10/3$.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you don't care much about the colors of the cars at this point. In fact, you don't even care about the other cars. In half the cases the red car will be before the blue car, and in the other half it'll be after. By linearity of expectation, you just count the number of pairs of red-blue cars and divide that by $2$ to get your answer.

Hope that helps,

Comment: My answer was marked "wrong" by the presumed downvoter, but to be fair "preceding a blue car" does not have to imply that you precede it immediately... I think it is pretty clear that my answers assumes that my definition of "preceding" just means that it arrives before in the line. For the other definition look at the other answers.